# BASH: error in C program that runs in subshell breaks the main shell

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that runs a list of small programs mostly written in C and Python, since the programs themselves are NOT bug free and they might crash or run into infinite loop, so in the BASH script, I run the programs in subshell so it won't break the main shell, here is what it likes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

for py_p in "${py_program_list[@]}"; do
    (python "$py_p") || echo "terminated!"
done

for c_p in "${c_program_list[@]}"; do
   ("$c_p") || echo "terminated!"
done
```

The problem is, when loops in python programs, the bash script won't be affected by any error in the python program which is what I expected. However, the bash script exit immediately if any C program exit with error.

UPDATE:

I am using BASH 3.2 in OSX 10.9.5

UPDATE 2:

Updated the question to make it more clear, sorry for the confusion. The problem I have is about the C program, the python part confirm the error in subshell won't affect the main shell but the C program breaks the rule.

Comment: So the problem is that python scripts hang when you ctrl-c them or they crash ?

Comment: So your C program segfaults?

Comment: @Quentin yes, I do trap the EXIT singal in the main shell, ctrl + c gives me a signal of 130 which is normal, and the return code in C program is also correctly trapped, although C program is call in the subshell.

Comment: @123 No, the Python scripts are fine, no matter I use Ctrl + C or they crash for some reason, they won't stop the main shell from running which is what I expect. But the C programs don't, type Ctrl + C when a C program is running will exit the bash script.

Comment: @4ae1e1 No, but I don't have a chance to test your case tho. What I did is I use Ctrl + C to terminate a C program runs in subshell which exist the main shell as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Python scripts are fine, no matter I use Ctrl + C or they crash
>   for some reason, they won't stop the main shell from running which is
>   what I expect. But the C programs don't, type Ctrl + C when a C
>   program is running will exit the bash script.

Python handles the interrupt signal itself (outputting `Traceback` …`KeyboardInterrupt`) and then terminates normally, returning the exit status **1** to `bash`.
Your C programs evidently don't handle the signal, so the default action is taken, to terminate the process; `bash` is informed that the program was terminated by signal **SIGINT**.
Now `bash` behaves differently depending on the kind of the child program's termination (normal or signaled): In the first case, it continues execution with `|| echo "terminated!"`, in the second case, it terminates itself, as you observed.
You can change that behavior by trapping the signal in your script, e. g. by inserting

```
trap "echo interrupted" INT
```

somewhere before the `for c_p` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't expect the question to be answer after 2 months :D. Yes, I solved the problem using something similar while I just don't understand what exactly happened behind the scene. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the Python programs exit status. Maybe they return the same value regardless they fact their execution was successful or not. So... basically, you cannot rely on their exit status.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem I have is, errors caused by C programs which are called inside subshell will break the main shell as well, but the python program won't (which is what I expected), any error thrown by python scripts only exit the subshell and can be caught by checking the `$?` in the main shell

Comment: Your `set -e` will cause the shell to exit as soon as a program (either C or Python) exits with non-zero status. Now... not necessarily programs (regardless their language) return zero if everything is ok and non-zero if they encounter an error. A badly coded program (in C, Python, Perl or whatever language you want) can easily return zero even if they fall into catastrophic errors.

Comment: I am sorry but that's not the case, since the C or Python program is running inside a subshell, so in normal cases, it should only break the subshell.